# Drawing small images on an existing PDF file by using PDF Libraries

Tags: android, svg, bitmap, pdf-generation, png

I’m working on an app that creates a PDF file and I need to draw some small images on it.

The problem is that the drawn images on the PDF are blurry and have very low quality.
I've also tried to draw the images without scaling them and the same happens, they are blurry.

This is the snippet where I draw one image (I'm not using iText)

```
Bitmap calendarBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.icon_200ppp_calendar);
pdfCanvas.drawBitmap(scaleToFitHeight(calendarBitmap, 16), xCoord, yCoord, null);

public Bitmap scaleToFitHeight(Bitmap b, int height) {
   float factor = height / (float) b.getHeight();
   return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) (b.getWidth() * factor), height, true);
}
```

I have the images in PNG and SVG (converted to VectorDrawable) and the result is the same.

This is the PNG:
[image: PNG file]

This is the XML generated from the SVG file through Android Studio: [SVG converted to VectorDrawable](https://pastebin.com/PJtatvyS)

These are the results:

[image: Blurry images zoom in]

[image: Blurry images zoom out]

Comment: Use a professional-level PDF inspector on your blurred image. Is it the same resolution as the original? The same size, in pixels? If not, there must be some re-sampling involved. PDFs is able to contain sharp bitmaps. (I assume it's not your viewer! Try another, for consistency's sake.)

Comment: The original PNG image is 48x48px and I apply a resize with the method I posted to get it down to 16x16. PDF inspector shows it's the same size and bits resolution.

Comment: Wait -- you downsize it yourself to 1/3 of the original size? Then why are you surprised the downsized image is not as sharp as the original? It has nothing to do with PDF, it's the downsizing that makes your image blurry. (Solution: don't.)

Comment: yes, I'm downsizing it because the size of the image is too big. I'll ask the designer an image at the exact size :) Thanks!
I've still have a doubt: do you know if it's the same downsizing an image that has 72dpi and another that has 300dpi?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Density of the image bigger by an X factor.
For example:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(..);
bm.setDensity(bm.getDensity()*4);
// try with different X's: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
```

This loss in quality happens because when you write to PDF it will automatically resize your bitmap to fit that Canvas resolution. Also if you resize your image, bitmap you have to be careful if you have a 50X50 image and you want to resize to 50X10 it will mess up the image. Instead try to resize the Bitmap by a factor:

```
bm.getWidth()/4, 
bm.getHeight()/4
```

and so on.